# ¿Cómo puedo escribir un archivo constantemente sin reescribir su contenido en NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, filesystem

Como ya dije, trabajo con **NodeJS**, y me gustaría hacer que mi programa añada "nuevas líneas" cuando un usuario manda un nuevo mensaje.

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código:

```
fs.writeFile(`${msg.channel.tracker}-${msg.channel.id}.txt`, `[${moment.utc(msg.createdAt).format('HH:mm:ss')}] ${msg.author.username} ❯ \n${msg.cleanContent}\n\n`, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Sin embargo, `fs.writeFile` reescribe el contenido del archivo. El contenido que tiene mi archivo **.txt** tiene el siguiente formato:

> [10:00:44] kyra ❯
>   Let's see if it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes usar [`appendFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_file_data_options_callback) para lograr esto.

```
fs.appendFile('message.txt', 'data to append', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');
});
```

saludos